# Show or hidden <divs> with click a list of elements with pure JS

Tags: javascript, toggle

How can I create a JS script that show/hidden and vice versa. Toggle divs based on it's state (`display:none` or `display:inline`) at clicking a list of elements? I'm struggling with the logic...

Here is the fiddle I tried [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danielcenoz/75rbLnwu/39/).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
  let menu = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  console.log(menu, panel);

  //recorre los elementos <li> y coloca un eventlistner 'click'
  for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    menu[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      //for(let j = 0; j < panel.length; j ++){
      panel[i].style.display == 'inline' ? panel[i].style.display = 'inline' : panel[i].style.display = 'none';
      //}
    });
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#one {
  display: inline;
}

#two {
  display: none;
}

#three {
  display: none;
}

#four {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ONE</li>
  <li>TWO</li>
  <li>THREE</li>
  <li>FOUR</li>
</ul>

<div class='panel' id='one'> ONE </div>
<div class='panel' id='two'> TWO </div>
<div class='panel' id='three'> THREE </div>
<div class='panel' id='four'> FOUR </div>
```

Comment: Fiddle is working but not hiding back. Is that the issue you are facing?

Comment: Guy see if this work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/75rbLnwu/104/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `panel display / hide` logic is wrong, I've corrected it and working example is below

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
  let menu = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

  for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    menu[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      panel[i].style.display == 'inline' ? panel[i].style.display = 'none' : panel[i].style.display = 'inline';
    });
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#one {
  display: inline;
}

#two {
  display: none;
}

#three {
  display: none;
}

#four {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ONE</li>
  <li>TWO</li>
  <li>THREE</li>
  <li>FOUR</li>
</ul>

<div class='panel' id='one'> ONE </div>
<div class='panel' id='two'> TWO </div>
<div class='panel' id='three'> THREE </div>
<div class='panel' id='four'> FOUR </div>
```

Comment: It works now, Javascript Lover - SKT, thanks for your help!

Comment: @DanielCenoz I've edited your question can you please approve that edit?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onclick="MyFunction()"` ([w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)) to get clicks from the li elements.

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="handleClick(1)">Panel 1</li>
  <li onclick="handleClick(2)">Panel 2</li>
  <li onclick="handleClick(3)">Panel 3</li>
  <li onclick="handleClick(4)">Panel 4</li> 
</ul>
```

Then a simple handler function to catch the click events

```
var handleClick = function(index) {
  let panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
  for (let i=0; i<panel.length; i++) {
    panel[i].style.display = (index - 1) == i ? 'inline' : 'none';
  }
};
```

Check out my working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojz3t62k/).

Also you had one div closing tag wrong in your fiddle.

```
   <div class="one panel" id="one">
     <div>
       PANEL #1
     </div>
   <div class="two panel" id="two">     
     <div>
       PANEL #2
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```